# Disable selection change in JFace TreeViewer

Tags: eclipse, selection, jface, treeviewer

I have a TreeViewer in my view. Whenever I press a button (say s), the viewer selects the first item in the tree starting with this letter (say stackoverflow). Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restricting all key events on Tree looks promising but you would loose navigating the tree structure and expand/collapse on tree node and all other functionality.

```
tree.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
         e.doit = false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I can live with the trade-off as this tree isn't really used for navigation by key inputs.